# Android-NestDK cannot initial thermostat object

Tags: java, android, nest-api

I want to create my own thermostat APP.

---

### My Method

1. Refer to MainActivity, I create new activity implements NestAPI.AuthenticationListener, Listener.ThermostatListener
2. Copy content of implements method and authenticate method from MainActivity

---

After run, the Authentication is success because of message "Authentication succeeded." in logcat. However, the Thermostat object mThermostat is still null and cannot get information in it.

p.s. I can modify the target temperature if copy MainActivity's mthermostat device ID.

---

Does anyone know how to initial thermostat object?

Comment: I don't know much about android and nothing about thermostats, but I'm sure you will need to show some your code.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation! I solve it when I'm trying to write a simple example lol Big Thanks:)

Comment: Good to hear that! This happens frequently :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

I solve it when I'm trying to write a simple example to upload here :I

I found I have to add `fetchData()` to set listener for thermostat, then `mthermostat` can be initial and update in `onThermostatUpdated(@NonNull Thermostat thermostat)`.

---

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.nestapi.codelab.demo.R;
import com.nestapi.codelab.demo.Settings;
import com.nestapi.lib.API.*;

public class Activity4Test extends Activity implements
    NestAPI.AuthenticationListener, Listener.ThermostatListener {

    private Listener mUpdateListener;
    private NestAPI mNestApi;
    private Thermostat mThermostat;
    private AccessToken mToken;

    TextView txvGet;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_4test);
        mNestApi = NestAPI.getInstance();//Initial NestAPI, connect Firebase
        mToken = Settings.loadAuthToken(this);//Loade AccessToken
        authenticate(mToken);

        txvGet = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txvGet);
    }

    private void authenticate(AccessToken token) {
        Log.v("Activity4Test", "Authenticating...");
        NestAPI.getInstance().authenticate(token, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess() {
        Log.v("Activity4Test", "Authentication succeeded.");
        fetchData();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(int errorCode) {
        Log.v("Activity4Test", "Authentication failed with error: " + errorCode);
    }

    private void fetchData() {
        Log.v("Activity4Test", "Fetching data...");

        mUpdateListener = new Listener.Builder()
                .setThermostatListener(this)
                .build();
        mNestApi.addUpdateListener(mUpdateListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onThermostatUpdated(@NonNull Thermostat thermostat) {
        Log.v("Activity4Test", String.format("Thermostat (%s) updated.", thermostat.getDeviceID()));
        mThermostat = thermostat;
    }
```